# vue cli environment variables

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

In webpack, I was able to set environment variables in my package.json like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev:visualise": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js --env entry=visualise",
  "dev:order": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js --env entry=order"
}
```

And then depending on which script I ran, I could access the environment var in my webpack config by doing:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => merge(common, {
    entry: `./src/_sites/${env.entry}/index.ts`,
}
```

Is this possible with vue-cli?

I've tried getting it from `process.env.entry`

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  chainWebpack: config => {
    console.log(process.env.entry);  // this is undefined
  },
```

or changing the module exports to

```
module.exports = env => defineConfig({
  chainWebpack: config => {
    console.log(env.entry);  // env is undefined
  },
```

but neither of these worked.  Is it possible to get the `env.entry` variable in the vue config?  Or is there a different way to only build specific entry points (or pages in vue.config - something like below)?

```
pages: {
    main: `Vue/Components/${process.env.entry}/main.ts`
},
```

Comment: you would normally just set this value in  local .env file to access it via process.env.entry

Comment: how would I change the .env file per build though - for example I may have a script for orders in which case I want the entry to be orders so depending on what I run, I want different environment variables

Comment: These are real env vars that aren't tied to webpack, you should be able to set them by means of OS, or cross-env for crossplatform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to the comment from oshell, I was able to change my build to

```
"build:dev-visualise": "vue-cli-service build --mode dev-visualise",
```

then I created a file `.env.dev-visualise` and inside that file I could create my environment variables:

```
ENTRY=visualise
NODE_ENV=development
```

Which I could then use in my vue.config:

```
pages: {
    main: `Vue/Components/${process.env.ENTRY}/main.ts`
},
```